# Could there be a plausible description for a kind of radioactive ore that can amplify the energy of a host or object, or potentially destroy it?

Tags: science-fiction, xenobiology, geology, chemistry, geophysics

This kind of ore should be rare (maybe from meteorites?), dangerous (radioactive?), but potentially very useful in a world where people have augmented abilities, cybernetic attachments, that sort of thing.

It could also be used to enhance machinery, vehicles, even weapons.

Seems like Astatine could come close to this.  Like an Astatine infused meteoric ore?  Chemistry is not my strong suit, help would be greatly appreciated with this one.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Radioactive material releases more energy when put next to more radioactive material on the whole, though you wouldn't want to be anywhere near such a reaction, much less in a cybernetic attachment.  You may be better off going more "science fiction" here and say, using exotic matter or something of that sort that distorts spacetime.

Comment: Destroying is quite easy. But what exactly do you mean by "amplify the energy of a host or object"? And by "enhance machinery"? There are trucks left in Зона відчуження Чорнобильської АЭС (Chernobyl Exclusion Zone), they are irradiated and there is nothing "enhanced" in them, not if we go with the common meaning of the word.

Comment: @Molot, the basic idea is that this substance is rare, is dangerous to handle, but if harnessed properly could potentially amplify whatever it is added to (i.e. cybernetic arm/weapon - made more powerful, a vehicle - more speed etc...).  I guess you could compare it to uranium. Regardless, I'm not going for realism here, but would like to shy away from fantasy/pseudo-science as much as I can.

Comment: @Neil, that could work.  What I'm caught up on is what to call it.  This ore (substance) is supposed to be what causes the main conflict in a story, a resource war of sorts.

Comment: If you don't want realism, and don't want fantasy/pseudo-science, then what do you want?

Comment: @Molot I'm just looking for ways to describe this rare substance (that people are willing to fight over).  It's just plausibility here, even though it is highly unrealistic, I don't want to describe it (said substance) as some kind of fairy dust.  Any sort of resemblance in our real world is all I'm going for, not 100% recreation of something that already exists.  Hope that clears it up.

Comment: Its typical to wait a while before accepting an answer just in case a more appropriate one comes along, just FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am thinking of the novel [Crystal Singer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Singer) by Anne McCaffrey.  It has such awesome cover art.  I am reminded of the Ecstasy of St.Theresa.

[image: Crystal Singer]

In any case, your minerals (radioactive or not) can resonate on a psionic frequency that can augment the abilities of psychics - or like a microphone / speaker system shatter their minds via overwhelming feedback.  You will need to hand wave up exactly what frequency this is but since you have psychic powers that is not such a heavy lift.  In Crystal Singer I seem to recall they needed to cut and mill the minerals properly to have them fulfill their function.  Maybe in your world they could be tailored to an individual, and a person would use another persons crystal only at great risk.

---

I was thinking more about this.  One could post flawed crystals as a defensive perimeter against psychics.  Maybe the really messed up ones might be perceived by nonpsychics too - a weird mumbling in the background as thoughts are amplified.  I was thinking also of psychic feedback - when there is feedback during a concert it is not just the musician that is affected.

Comment: This makes more sense and fits the storyline better.  After reading your answer, crystals or gemstones seem more to fit the story line than radioactive minerals.  The idea is that it's 'supernatural' (for discussion sake) properties are discovered accidentally, initially they were sought after for profit... like a gold rush of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would be slightly possible for this to happen but the chances are second to none. If this did happen though, it would have to be charged, possible from a lightning strike, and with that energy be able to reproduce the electrical charge and slowly increase its voltage. This would not be possible with the elements that we have already discovered tough and if it was radioactive, which you say it should be, then it would simply explode.